# Contextmenu and target with dataTable

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable, contextmenu, target

I'm doing jsf with primefaces5.0 and here's my scenario:

I have a page contains a dataTable with contextmenu like this:
[image]
When I clicked the contextmenu, I want to popup another "window" (not "tab") with information about the selected data, for example, the String "data1".

However, it can't be done whether I use `action` or `url` parameter in the `p:menuitem`.

When I use `action` parameter, `anotherPage` shows but in the original window, while the opened new window is empty:
[image]

And if I change `action="/anotherPage"` into `url="/anotherPage.xhtml"`,`anotherPage` shows in the new window but with no information about the selected data:(Please note that the title has changed into "Another Page")
[image]

Here's what I've done:

**Facelet:**

```
 <h:form>
        <p:contextMenu for="dataTable">
            <p:menuitem value="clickMe" icon="ui-icon-gear" 
                        onclick="window.open('', 'Popup', config = 'scrollbars=yes,status=no,toolbar=no,location=no,menubar=no,width=1300,height=370').focus();" 
                        target="Popup" actionListener="#{mainBean.showPopup()}" action="/anotherPage"/>
        </p:contextMenu>
        <p:dataTable id="dataTable" value="#{mainBean.dataList}" var="data" rowIndexVar="index" emptyMessage="Loading..." 
                     selectionMode="single" selection="#{mainBean.selectedStr}" rowKey="#{data}">
            <p:column headerText="data">
                <p:outputLabel value="#{data}"/>
            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>    
    </h:form>
```

**BackingBean:**

```
private List<String> dataList=new ArrayList<>();
private String selectedStr="";

public void showPopup(){
    Map<String, Object> reqMap=FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestMap();
    reqMap.put("param", selectedStr);
}
```

**AnotherPage.xhtml:**

```
<p:outputLabel value="This is the selected String:"/>
<p:outputLabel value="#{anotherPageBean.txt}"/>
```

**AnotherPageBean:**

```
private String txt;    

@PostConstruct
public void init(){
    Map<String, Object> reqMap=FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestMap();
    txt=(String) reqMap.get("param");
}
```

Thank you very much.

---

### **Update**

I did a lot survey and find out something:

1. **`Target` attribute of menuitem is not rendered for `action`**, it's a [known issue](https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=1008) and won't be fixed.
2. Menuitem supports `f:params` to pass parameters according to [optimus.prime](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?p=11570&sid=e60a9b23abb8773a7f89ddb733e171c6#p11570).
3. When I use `url`, the parameters can't be find in request map, which probably means it's a brand new request so that I can't find what I put in the reqMap.
4. Maybe I can put parameters in session map instead of request map because of what I mentioned in 3.
5. Neither `action` nor `actionListener` be called if I use `url`.

Comment: Have you tried using `target="_blank"` on your `menuItem`?

Comment: I tried that and the page still shows in the original window...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to what I've said in the **update** section of my question, I found a workaround.
Please note that I believe this is just a workaround, hope there are some normal ways to solve it.

As **target attribute of menuitem is not rendered for action** I can only use `url`.
So I tried using `f:params` to pass parameters with `url` but still in vain because the 3rd point I mentioned in the **update** section I think.

After that, I tried put parameters in session map through backing bean and use `action` to call the method. However, it still won't work because `action` is not called if I use `url`.

According to this thought, I call the method outside the `menuitem`.
I add a event to the `dataTable` and call method there:

```
<p:dataTable id="dataTable" value="#{mainBean.dataList}" var="data" rowIndexVar="index" emptyMessage="Loading..." 
                     selectionMode="single" selection="#{mainBean.selectedStr}" rowKey="#{data}">
        <p:ajax event="contextMenu" listener="#{mainBean.setParam()}"/>
        <p:column headerText="data">
            <p:outputLabel value="#{data}"/>
        </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

And in the Backing Bean:

```
 public void setParam(){
    HttpSession session=(HttpSession) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSession(false);
    session.setAttribute("param", selectedStr);
}
```

So I can get info through session in `anotherPageBean` like:

```
 @PostConstruct
public void init(){
    HttpSession session=(HttpSession) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSession(false);
    txt=(String) session.getAttribute("param");
    session.removeAttribute("param");
}
```

Please note that the attribute should be removed after the info is got.
And this is the result:
[image]
Just for those who have the same problem.